# shell script - How to output the owner of a file

Tags: linux, unix, shell-script, ownership

Is there a command to output the owner of a file, and nothing else? I suppose I could use `ls` and run it through `sed`, but if there is a better way, I would definitely use it.

Comment: Do you need that more often? You could make a lttle perl script or even a little c program to return a specific info on a given filename.

Comment: @ott I could... but that is less portable(?). I would prefer to use programs already on a computer, than to have to compile my own.

Comment: @BenjiWiebe: Perl tends to be very portable. You could use something like `for my $file (@ARGV) {$uid = (stat $file)[4]; $name = (getpwuid $uid)[0]; print "$name\n"}` or `print map {"$_\n"} map {(getpwuid $_)[0]} map {(stat $_)[4]} @ARGV` (whichever looks nicer to you)

Comment: @grawity Perl is not installed everywhere... but show me a Linux system that does not have `stat` and `bash`/`sh` installed.

Comment: @BenjiWiebe: I can show you a few BSD systems that use [completely different options](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=stat&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD+9.0-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) for `stat`.

Comment: @grawity As long as it works on Fedora. I am... uh... fluent? in bash scripting, and I know very very little Perl. However, if I was distributing this software I would consider learning and using Perl.

Comment: @BenjiWiebe: when you look for a reply applying to a specific OS (eg Fedora), or a range of OSes (eg Gnu/Linuxes), better not to tag it Unix. Unix is a standard and imply standard compliant answers when available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
stat -c %U file.txt
```

`ls` is a tool for interactively looking at file information. Its output is formatted for humans and will cause bugs in scripts. **Use `globs` or `find` instead**. Understand why: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Thanks a lot. I like jilliagre's function, but I wanted a command to do it without parsing the ouput of another command.

Comment: Sweet, a new terminal command to play with! I never knew about the stat command, but I will now abuse it in every way I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

I would use that function:

```
lso() { ls -dl ${1:?usage: lso file} | awk '{print $3;exit}'; }
```

Edit:

- I thought about `stat` but I try to avoid using anything non standard when possible. I sticked with something portable (i.e. POSIX) as your question is tagged linux **and** unix, not just linux with which `stat` is quite standard..
- As this question triggered a discussion about valid usernames, these are also defined by a Unix standard to be a string composed exclusively of characters from this list:

> A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
>
> a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
>
> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 . _ -

with the additional restriction for the hyphen not to be the first character.

I assumed no space was allowed. Just like anything else which is non-portable this can lead to unexpected results not only with my small function but with many Unix/Linux CLI utilities.

Comment: Might work great until you have a username with perhaps a space in it...

Comment: @MichaelKjörling On Fedora 17: `sudo adduser "foo bar"` outputs 
`adduser: invalid user name 'foo bar'` but it works fine if you try "foobar" (without a space). Therefore, spaces are not valid in usernames.

Comment: Where in the question does it even specify Linux? I see a `unix` tag as well...

Comment: @MichaelKjörling The title starts out "linux - shell script -...". And then of course, there is the linux tag.

Comment: @BenjiWiebe: Spaces *are* valid in usernames, regardless of what `adduser` says about them. In fact, they're commonly used on Linux systems joined to MS Active Directory domains.

Comment: @grawity OK. I did not know that.

Comment: (I'm pretty sure the only actually invalid character in usernames is `:`. In a way, this is really similar to filenames, which allow everything except `/`.)

Comment: @grawity: Unix/Linux are quite restrictive and certainly do not allow local usernames with a space (see my updated reply). Windows is quite relaxed with what it accepts but is however more restrictive than allowing anything but a colon. The backslash for example is used to separate a domain from a username so cannot be used in the latter. There are likely several other restrictions.

Comment: @jlliagre: Linux glibc certainly does not filter usernames in `getpwnam()` or `getpwuid()` at all. Whether it's `That Guy:*:1000:1000::/home/That Guy:/bin/sh` in one's /etc/passwd, or an account returned by nss-ldap or nss-sss or nss-winbind, there are no such restrictions.

Comment: @grawity, granted you can hack your password/shadow file that way but that username is still invalid and breaking the Unix standard.  Linux pwck will complain: `# pwck --> invalid user name 'That Guy'` . I agree remote usernames can be almost anything but then they might lead to problems.

Comment: @BenjiWiebe Yes, there is a `linux` tag. There is *also* a `unix` tag. Unix is not Linux, and the same rules certainly need not apply to both (let alone specific variants of Unix; what's to say that Mac OS X and Solaris do things the same way?).